# Access CSS file after htaccess modified url

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, web

I am using this htaccess file to re-write my urls:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Friend SEO url
#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
#RewriteRule ^ /%2/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*?)/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^ /%1.php [L]
```

The url rewriting works perfectly fine (for example, mypage/web-store/ can be used instead of mypage/web-store.html).

The problem however, is that my rewritten url can't retrieve the CSS file correctly. If I use the normal url however, I have no problem at all because the CSS file is in a subfolder of mypage. But with the url rewrite, it looks for the css file inside the folder /web-store/, which doesn't exist...

Anyone knows a way to counter this ?

Comment: Sounds like you are using a relative url to your stylesheet.  If you use an absolute url you won't have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either change your URLs to absolute URLs (add a leading `/`) or you can set a relative URL base in the header of your pages:

```
<base href="http://example.com/mypage/" />
```

Where "example.com" is the domain name of your site and the `/mypage/` is where the css is at.

If all else still fails, you can try to rewrite the proper page:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ([^/]+\.css)$ /path/to/styles/$1 [L,R=301]
```